# PHP dynamic JSON invalid

Tags: php, json, dynamic, datatable

I am trying to get a dataTable on a page called "locations.php" but i am still get a JSON invalid error.
I generate the JSON dynamically using this php code  on "get_SR_Locations.php":

```
$myjson = array();
foreach ($locationList as $list) :
  $json= array(
    "id" => addslashes($list['id']),
    "name" => addslashes($list['name']),
  "address" => addslashes($list['address']),
    "telephone" => addslashes($list['telephone']),
  "emailaddress" => addslashes($list['email'])
    );
    array_push($myjson, $json);
endforeach; 
$mj=array("data"=>$myjson);
echo json_encode($mj);
```

The generated JSON looks something like this:

> {"data":[{"id":"108","name":"Sportpark","address":"Karspstreet 501","telephone":"0123456789","emailaddress":"sport@mail.com"},{"id":"2","name":"Blaashal","address":"Gustavstreet 2920","telephone":"","emailaddress":"sporting@mailing.com"}]}

So when I put this in a JSON validator it says: **VALID JSON**
But I still get an invalid JSON warning by ajax.

On locations.php I have this code:
**HTML**

```
    <table id="displayTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered display compact" style="width:100%">
   <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Address</th>
       <th>Telephone</th>
</tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
   <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Address</th>
       <th>Telephone</th>
   </tr>
   </tfoot>
  </table>
```

**And this JQUERY**

```
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return 'So Far .... NOT so Good';
}

 $('#SR_sendForm').click(function(){
                    $('#displayTable').DataTable(
                        {
                        "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                        "scrollY": $(window).height()-($(window).height()/10),
                            "scrollX": true,
                            "ajax": 'pages/get_SR_Locations.php?fdr='+$('#FDR').val()+'&s_term='+$('#searchterm').val()+'&city='+$('#city').val()+'&searchgroup='+$('#searchgroup').val(),
                            "columns": [
                            {
                                "className":      'details-control',
                                "orderable":      false,
                                "data":           null,
                                "defaultContent": ''
                            },
                            { "data": "name" },
                            { "data": "address" },
                            { "data": "telephone" }
                        ]
                        }
                    );
                $('#responseTable').show();
        }
    }); 

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#responseTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
```

And this is the error I get:

> DataTables warning: table id=displayTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

What is wrong?

Comment: what if you put that json into datatables' data (instead of going via ajax) - just to test...

Comment: and are you sure that nothing else is echoed in `get_SR_Locations.php`?

Comment: I'm not sure about this datatables thing, but in your definition of the columns, you are missing `"emailaddress"` or `{ "data": "emailaddress" }`  if it works like jQgid, it's probably not going to like that.  Because that field is in your JSON but not defined in the table data.  But that is just a guess, because Like I said I never used that plugin.

Comment: I loaded get_SR_Locations.php output in a DIV to see if it only echoed the JSON and yes it does.

For the datatables it would not be a problem if you don't use all in the columns. But you need all the data if you are going to show more information if the user clicks on the row.

Comment: Jeff ... what do you mean loading the json  into the datatables data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Jeff.... I did what you said ... Add json to the data instead of going via ajax.
So the solution is:

I made an tempDIV to load the data from get_SR_Locations.php

```
<div class="row" id="tempDIV" style="display: none"></div>
```

then I load the data and I use the callback for errors etc.

```
$('#tempDIV').load('pages/get_SR_Locations.php?fdr='+$('#FDR').val()+'&s_term='+$('#searchterm').val()+'&city='+$('#city').val()+'&searchgroup='+$('#searchgroup').val(), function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
            if(statusTxt == "success"){
                $('#displayTable').DataTable(
                    {

                    "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                    "scrollY": $(window).height()-($(window).height()/10),
                        "scrollX": true,
                        "data": JSON.parse($.trim($('#tempDIV').text())),
                        "columns": [
                        {
                            "className":      'details-control',
                            "orderable":      false,
                            "data":           null,
                            "defaultContent": ''
                        },
                        { "data": "name" },
                        { "data": "address" },
                        { "data": "telephone" }
                    ]
                    }
                );
            $('#responseTable').show();
       }
            if(statusTxt == "error"){
            $('#responseTable').html("<b>Oops</b><br>Houston we have a problem");
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            $('#responseTable').show();
        }   
        });
```

**And a last modification in get_SR_Locations.php:**

I removed this line:

*$mj=array("data"=>$myjson);*

```
 $myjson = array();
foreach ($locationList as $list) :
  $json= array(
    "id" => addslashes($list['id']),
    "name" => addslashes($list['name']),
  "address" => addslashes($list['address']),
    "telephone" => addslashes($list['telephone']),
  "emailaddress" => addslashes($list['email'])
    );
    array_push($myjson, $json);
endforeach; 
echo json_encode($myjson);
```